# Django URL path redirect

Tags: django, django-urls

I have my urls.py split into two files:

Project-level urls.py:

```
from myapp.urls import MYAPP_URLS

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (...)
)
urlpatterns += MYAPP_URLS
```

Then on my app-level urls.py:

```
MYAPP_URLS = patterns('',
    ('^my_profile/$', my_profile),
    ('^submit/$', submit),
)
```

Now the problem is the following: I want to make it so all my app URLs are put in a sub-URL.

That is:

```
mysite.com/my_profile
mysite.com/submit
```

Become:

```
mysite.com/suburl/my_profile
mysite.com/suburl/submit
```

I already refactored the app URLs into its own file (and separated them from the main urls.py as you can see above) in order to facilitate this, but I have no idea what the next step is now.

Can somebody help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project urls file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^suburl/', include('myapp.urls')),
    ...
)
```

More information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this.  In the primary url.py file, import your sub-app url files like this:

```
MYAPP_URLS = patterns('',
(r'^somepage/$', someaction),
(r'^mysite.com/suburl/', include('mysite.subapp.urls')),
)
```